# UBlox NAV_PVT message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5

Tags: python, character-encoding

Does anybody know how to decode the `NAV_PVT` message in python?

I tried the `UTF-8` but it I get this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I can't find the right decode format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the file as binary, because it is binary. UBlox has a nice documentation on various formats/protocols. Check them

E.g. https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28UBX-13003221%29.pdf page 332. Is this what you are looking for?

Or if you were using some libraries, you should check such documentation. But I assume or you mixed up the binary with ascii version, or you are just using the binary protocol.